# Why does requiring a package in .Rprofile not override a base function?

Tags: r

I'm creating a package that defines a `cm` function, which clashes with `grDevices::cm`.

When I load the package manually I get a warning that notifies me of the conflict, but the `cm` function gets overwritten. If I add `library(my_package)` to my `.Rprofile`, `grDevices::cm` does not get overwritten.

How can I force this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried `library(grDevices);library(my_package)` in your `.Rprofile`?

Comment: You're right. That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real way to fix the conflict is renaming your function. By placing the call in your `.Rprofile`, R loads your package before loading `grDevices`, which means that the `cm` variable when called from the global environment will point to the `grDevices::cm`, so that now *your* function is inaccessible without using `::`. You do not have control over what order your users will load packages in.

Why are you exporting a function named `cm`? If you really want, you can force R to load your package occuring after `grDevices` so that it gets priority in the search path:

```
library(my_package, pos =
  if(length(tmp <- which(search() == 'package:grDevices') + 1) == 0) 2 else tmp)
```

The `if` statement is necessary in case `grDevices` is not currently loaded, in which case the above will use the default behavior of `library` (note this is really really rare since this package is almost always loaded).